# Filtering data bolt Storm

Tags: filter, apache-storm, topology

I have a simple Storm topology which reads the data from Kafka, parses and extracts message fields. I would like to filter the stream of tuples by one of the fields values and perform counting aggregation on another one. How can I do this in Storm?
I haven't found respective methods for tuples (filter, aggregate) so should I perform these functions directly on the field values?

Here is a topology:

```
topologyBuilder.setSpout("kafka_spout", new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig), 1)
topologyBuilder.setBolt("parser_bolt", new ParserBolt()).shuffleGrouping("kafka_spout")
topologyBuilder.setBolt("transformer_bolt", new KafkaTwitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("parser_bolt")

val config = new Config()
cluster.submitTopology("kafkaTest", config, topologyBuilder.createTopology())
```

I have set up KafkaTwitterBolt for counting and filtering with parsed fields. I've managed to filter the whole list of values only not by specific field:

```
class KafkaTwitterBolt() extends BaseBasicBolt{

 override def execute(input: Tuple, collector: BasicOutputCollector): Unit = {
  val tweetValues = input.getValues.asScala.toList
  val filterTweets = tweetValues
     .map(_.toString)
     .filter(_ contains "big data")
  val resultAllValues = new Values(filterTweets)
  collector.emit(resultAllValues)
 }

 override def declareOutputFields(declarer: OutputFieldsDeclarer): Unit = {
  declarer.declare(new Fields("created_at", "id", "text", "source", "timestamp_ms",
   "user.id", "user.name", "user.location", "user.url", "user.description", "user.followers_count",
   "user.friends_count", "user.lang", "user.favorite_count", "entities.hashtags"))
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Storm core API does not allows that, in order to perform filtering on any field Trident should be used (it has built-in filter function).
The code would look like this:

```
 val tridentTopology = new TridentTopology()

    val stream = tridentTopology.newStream("kafka_spout",
      new KafkaTridentSpoutOpaque(spoutConfig))
      .map(new ParserMapFunction, new Fields("created_at", "id", "text", "source", "timestamp_ms",
        "user.id", "user.name", "user.location", "user.url", "user.description", "user.followers_count",
        "user.friends_count", "user.favorite_count", "user.lang", "entities.hashtags"))
    .filter(new LanguageFilter)
```

Filtering function itself:

```
class LanguageFilter extends BaseFilter{

  override def isKeep(tuple: TridentTuple): Boolean = {
    val language = tuple.getStringByField("user.lang")
    println(s"TWEET: $language")
    language.contains("en")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59805582/8845188 is a little wrong. The Storm core API does allow filtering and aggregation, you just have to write the logic yourself.

A filtering bolt is just a bolt that discards some tuples, and passes others on. For instance, the following bolt will filter out tuples based on a string field:

```
class FilteringBolt() extends BaseBasicBolt{

 override def execute(input: Tuple, collector: BasicOutputCollector): Unit = {
  val values = input.getValues.asScala.toList
  if ("Pass me".equals(values.get(0))) {
    collector.emit(values)
  }
  //Emitting nothing means discarding the tuple
 }

 override def declareOutputFields(declarer: OutputFieldsDeclarer): Unit = {
  declarer.declare(new Fields("some-field"))
 }
}
```

An aggregating bolt is just a bolt that collects multiple tuples, and then emits a new aggregate tuple anchored in the original tuples:

```
class AggregatingBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
  List<Tuple> tuplesToAggregate = ...;
  int counter = 0;

 override def execute(input: Tuple): Unit = {
  tuplesToAggregate.add(input);
  counter++;
  if (counter == 10) {
    Values aggregateTuple = ... //create a new set of values based on tuplesToAggregate
    collector.emit(tuplesToAggregate, aggregateTuple) //This anchors the new aggregate tuple to all the original tuples, so if the aggregate fails, the original tuples are replayed.
    for (Tuple t : tuplesToAggregate) {
      collector.ack(t); //Ack the original tuples now that this bolt is done with them
      //Note that you MUST emit before you ack, or the at-least-once guarantee will be broken.
    }
    tuplesToAggregate.clear();
    counter = 0;
  }
  //Note that we don't ack the input tuples until the aggregate gets emitted. This lets us replay all the aggregated tuples in case the aggregate fails
 }
}
```

Note that for aggregation, you will need to extend `BaseRichBolt` and do acking manually, since you want to delay acking a tuple until it has been included in an aggregate tuple.